# Custom package structure confusion

Tags: python

I have a simple package:

```
package
│
├── package1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
│ 
└── package2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module3.py
    └── module4.py
```

In `module2.py` I have that code:

```
def function1():
    pass
```

In `module3.py`:

```
from package1.module1 import function1
```

But got an error:

```
\Desktop\package\package2\module3.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package1.module1 import function1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'
```

Comment: What command did you execute that gave you the error?

Comment: In order to be able to import `package1` (or `package2`), the directory `package` needs to be on the import path. There's a bunch of ways to make that happen (e.g. relying on `package` being your CWD, installing your project as a distribution package, ...). Is there there a particular way you expect `package` to be added to the import path, or are you looking for ways to make sure that it is?